# jmock create mock object encounter illegalargumentException

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmock

When I was using jmock, somehow it fails at this line

```
Mock mockObject = mock(Classname.class, new Class[] { Position.class, Position.class, List.class,
            List.class, String.class, int.class}, new Object[] { null, null, null, null, null, null });
```

I'm using jmock1, I'm pretty sure the ctor is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are doing mocking like this in JMockit??

I don't see familiar syntax as JMOckit.
The above code which you paste is not clear enough to understand.Is this the parameterized private method which you are trying to mock?

[Getting started with JMockit: Standard Document](http://jmockit.org/gettingStarted.html)
[Simple link with example quick to refer](http://abhinandanmk.blogspot.in/2012/06/jmockit-tutoriallearn-it-today-with.html)